# SyntaxError in React Typescript Project But No Compiler Errors in IDE

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, jestjs

My project is a Chrome OS application built using Typescript and `create-react-aoo`.

The following is the offending typescript file:

```js
import Keys from "./Keys";
import Volume from "./Volume"
import Block from './Block'
import EventHandler from "../utility/EventHandler"

abstract class ChromeVolume implements Volume {
    readonly error: EventHandler<Volume, Error> = new EventHandler<Volume, Error>(this);

    async abstract load<T extends Keys>(keys: T): Promise<Block>

    async abstract save<T extends object>(items: T): Promise<void>

    async abstract clear(): Promise<void>
}

export default ChromeVolume
```

I receive the following error when trying to run Jest tests using `react-scripts test`:

```
Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: ...\ChromeVolume.ts: Unexpected token, expected "(" (12:19)

      10 |     readonly error: EventHandler<Volume, Error> = new EventHandler<Volume, Error>(this);
      11 | 
    > 12 |     async abstract load<T extends Keys>(keys: T): Promise<Block>
         |                    ^
      13 | 
      14 |     async abstract save<T extends object>(items: T): Promise<void>
      15 | 

      at Object.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6322:17)
      at Object.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7638:16)
      at Object.expect (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7624:28)
      at Object.parseFunctionParams (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10495:10)
      at Object.parseFunctionParams (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5570:11)
      at Object.parseMethod (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9304:10)
      at Object.pushClassMethod (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10743:30)
      at Object.pushClassMethod (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5540:11)
      at Object.parseClassMemberWithIsStatic (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10687:14)
      at Object.parseClassMemberWithIsStatic (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5440:11)
```

Comment: I have had a similar issue before, your compiler most likely thinks `<T extends Keys>` is a react tag, have you tried changing the order of the abstract and async keywords and generic declaration?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the following changed file:

```js
import Keys from "./Keys";
import Volume from "./Volume"
import Block from './Block'
import EventHandler from "../utility/EventHandler"

abstract class ChromeVolume implements Volume {
    readonly error: EventHandler<Volume, Error> = new EventHandler<Volume, Error>(this);

    abstract async load<T extends Keys>(keys: T): Promise<Block>

    abstract async save<T extends object>(items: T): Promise<void>

    abstract async clear(): Promise<void>
}

export default ChromeVolume
```

I'm not sure why changing the order of the `abstract` and `async` keywords mattered, but the issue is now resolved.